# rspec is not showing in gem list after installation?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

After installing rspec it is not showing in gem list.
after running rspec --version I am getting this message:

```
Khalids-MacBook-Pro:~ KNaseem$ rspec --version
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rspec-core' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/khalidnaseem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Users/khalidnaseem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:320:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: And you are not getting errors when you `gem install rspec`?

Comment: Not getting any errors when installing rspec, please see below:

Comment: Khalids-MBP:~ KNaseem$ sudo gem install rspec --version 2.8.0
Successfully installed rspec-2.8.0
Parsing documentation for rspec-2.8.0
1 gem installed

Comment: Not sure why `gem install rspec` doesn't install dependencies, but you can try manually `gem install rspec-core`

Comment: after running the command sudo gem install rspec -core, i am getting this:

Comment: Khalids-MBP:~ KNaseem$ sudo gem install rspec-core
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/rspec